# How to use regex in str_replace (stringr) to rename variables in R

Tags: r, regex, replace, stringr

I'm using R 4.3.1

I have a data frame with several variables, including years. The years are formatted this way:
`X1960..YR1960.`
I would like to rename all the variables following this pattern to a simplified version:
`Y1960`

The dataframe contains variables from `X1960..YR1960.` to `X2022..YR2022.`

My current approach:

```
names(df) <- str_replace(names(df), "X\\d\\d\\d\\d\\.\\.YR*.", "Y")
```

Result of the current approach: `Y960.`

I don't understand the following things: Why is the first digit of the year omitted. Is the `R` a special character? If so, how can i escape it correctly?
How do I get rid of the last dot? I tried escaping it too, but that yielded no matches to the regex.
How works `*` exactly as a placeholder?

Comment: The unescaped `.` matches the digit after `R` as an unescaped `.` matches any character but line break chars. Did you mean to match and keep what is between `R` and last `.`? Like `str_replace(names(df), "^X\\d{4}\\.{2}YR*(.*)\\.$", "Y\\1")`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, thanks. I think your solution is equivalent to my modification of @Tim 's answer, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: No, it is not the same. My pattern does not care what kind of text comes after `YR`, `\1` only matches the same four digits captured into Group 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `sub()` here for a simple base R option:

```r
x <- "X1960..YR1960"
x_out <- sub("X(\\d{4})\\.\\.YR\\1", "\\1", x)
x_out
```

Comment: Thank You!
I made some changes, but it works perfectly:
`names(X) <- sub("X(\\d{4})\\.\\.YR\\1\\.", "Y\\1", names(X))`
I added an escaped dot `\\.` at the end of the regex and an `Y` to the beginning of the replacement to yield the format i desired.

Answer (score 1):

If all your names truly look like this, complicated regex isn't necessarily needed - a non-regex solution would be to simply pluck the last four digits using `substr` and prepend "Y" using `paste0`

```
df <- data.frame(`X1960..YR1960` = NA, 
                  `X1970..YR1970` = NA, 
                  `X2022..YR2022` = NA)
paste0("Y", 
       substr(names(df), nchar(names(df))-3, nchar(names(df))))

# [1] "Y1960" "Y1970" "Y2022"
```

Note I couldn't tell if there was truly a `.` at the end of the name (i.e., `X1960..YR1960.`). - if so, then you would simply tweak:

```
df <- data.frame(`X1960..YR1960.` = NA, 
                  `X1970..YR1970.` = NA, 
                  `X2022..YR2022.` = NA)
paste0("Y", 
       substr(names(df), nchar(names(df))-4, nchar(names(df))-1))

# [1] "Y1960" "Y1970" "Y2022"
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative! I wasn't aware of the possibilities `substr` offers.